# Why UV Unwrap node on a cube results in a stretched texture?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I am trying to understand how the "UV Unwrap" node works and created a very simple setup to test it.

In doing so, I came up with an unexpected result:

[image: un unwrap setup]

To my understanding, this setup should mark all edges as seams. Unwrapping from there should result in square shaped UV maps. From what I can see, however, the results are not square and the shapes are rotated.

I expect square texture areas on each side, not stretched or rotated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why this does not work for you as expected is because a UV map is always defined in the domain *Face Corner*.

A face consists of several corner points, and exactly these positions are defined with a UV-Map.

In your case you would have to change the *Attribute Domain* to *Face Corner* in the *Group Output*:

[image]

By the way, another option would be to use the node `Store Named Attribute` if you want to:

[image]

PS: by the way, the documentation for [UV Unwrap Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/uv/uv_unwrap.html) states: *"The node implicitly performs a Pack Islands operation upon completion, because the results may not be generally useful otherwise."*

This means that strictly speaking you don't need the [Pack UV Islands](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/uv/pack_uv_islands.html) node.