# Placing / mapping an image texture onto selected face or faces using geometry nodes and the shader editor

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes, uv-image-editor, shader-nodes

Placing / mapping an image texture onto selected face or faces using geometry nodes and the Shader Editor

I'm trying to place an image texture onto a **selected face or faces** of an object but its placing / filling the whole object.

My thought process was to:

1. Unwrap the objects UV's in geometry nodes.
2. Place the texture image from the Shader Editor on the selected face or faces.

Example:
I create a grid in geometry nodes.[image: img1]

I used the UV Unwrap node to place the texture on the selected face but it covers the entire object or it's to large.

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

The Shader Editor setup

[image: img4]

I'm trying to get it to look like this (with the F4 image filling the selected face or faces)

[image: img5]

PS: I'm using Blender 4.0.2 here's the blend file.
[image]

And the image texture file

[image: image texture]

Comment: Could you please share your Blender file and the "F4" picture to give it a try ?

Comment: Sure I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

Following is a proposal separating the selected faces before computing local UV map and setting the material with image texture. **Beware that the UV map is defined in the *Face Corner* domain when setting the *Store Named Attribute* node.**

[image: GN graph]

**Resources:**

- Blender file: [image]
- See also [Why UV Unwrap node on a cube results in a stretched texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274528/why-uv-unwrap-node-on-a-cube-results-in-a-stretched-texture)

Comment: Thanks! One question I have is why is everything else white / opaque instead of transparent?

Comment: With "Viewport Shading" set to "Material Preview", surfaces without explicit material info are rendered by default with a material of index 0 (see in "Spreadsheet Editor" the column "material_index" for "Face" domain). And this material is white, not transparent. You can check that in a fresh Blender file with just the initial cube. It is rendered the same.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to @StefLAncien here's the final which I think will help people.
**Apply textures to specific faces**.

Works for **EEVEE**

**EEVEE Settings**

[image: EEVEE]

And **Cycles**

**Cycle Settings**

[image: CYCLES]

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image]